# Is Apex Code Consolidated per object the best way?

Tags: apex, trigger, npsp

Our vendor has consolidated apex per object, however, when they added new apex code for us under a specific object - it is now throwing an error (exceeded CPU limit). When looking at this code, is this the best way to do it? Have we hit the limit on customizations for this object or are we just writing redundant code?

```
global class NPSPDataImportBatch_TDTM extends npsp.TDTM_Runnable {

/**
* @User story: Entry Type JIRA ticket PFMN-1082
* @Method name: run
* @Description: TDTM Run method works based on the trigger handler setup
* @Param: new list, old list, trigger action, sobject
* @Return: DML Wrapper
* @Date: 14 Feb 2022
**/
global override npsp.TDTM_Runnable.DmlWrapper run(List<SObject> newlist,List<SObject> oldlist,npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action triggerAction,Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult) {
    system.debug('**** NPSPDataImportBatch_TDTM');
    npsp.TDTM_Runnable.dmlWrapper dmlWrapper = new npsp.TDTM_Runnable.DmlWrapper();
    List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c> lstNewDataImport = (List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c>) newlist;
    List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c> lstOldDataImport = (List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c>) oldlist;
    
    //try{
        if (triggerAction == npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action.BeforeInsert) {
            system.debug('*** BEFORE INSERT DataImport Batch TDTM');
        }
        if (triggerAction == npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action.BeforeUpdate) {
            system.debug('*** $$$ BEFORE UPDATE DataImport Batch TDTM'); 
            validateAllocation(lstNewDataImport,lstOldDataImport);
            validateBatch(lstNewDataImport, False);
            setLockedDownOnOppAndPayment(lstNewDataImport); 
        }
        if (triggerAction == npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action.AfterUpdate) {
            system.debug('*** $$$ AFTER UPDATE DataImport Batch');
            
        }
        if (triggerAction == npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action.AfterInsert) {
            system.debug('*** $$$ AFTER INSERT DataImport Batch');
        }
    /*}
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('*** $$$ Error Message => '+e.getMessage());                                             
        System.debug('*** $$$ Message stackTrace => '+e.getStackTraceString());                                             
    }*/
    return dmlWrapper;
}
    
/**
* @User story: PFM-324
* @Method name: setLockedDownOnOppAndPayment 
* @Description: set Locked down field true on payment and opportunity when accosited batch status is 'Ready to Post' or 'Closed'
* @Param: new list
* @Return: none
* @Date: 03 June 2022
**/
public static void setLockedDownOnOppAndPayment(List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c> lstDataImport) {
    system.debug('## setLockedDownOnOppAndPayment ===>'+lstDataImport);
    Set<ID> setBatchIds = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> setOppIds = new Set<ID>();
    for(npsp__DataImportBatch__c obj : lstDataImport){            
        if(obj.NGOC_Batch_Status__c=='Ready to Post' || obj.NGOC_Batch_Status__c=='Closed') {
            setBatchIds.add(obj.id);
        }                
    }
    
    system.debug('## setBatchIds ===>'+setBatchIds);
    
    List<npe01__OppPayment__c> lstPaymentToUpdate = new List<npe01__OppPayment__c>();
    List<Opportunity> lstOpportunityToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    if(setBatchIds.size()>0) {
        for (npe01__OppPayment__c payment: [select  Locked_Down__c, Batch__c, npe01__Opportunity__c from npe01__OppPayment__c where Batch__c in :setBatchIds]) {                
            system.debug('## payment ===>'+payment);
            payment.Locked_down__c = true;                
            lstPaymentToUpdate.add(payment);  
            
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Locked_down__c = true ;
            opp.Id = payment.npe01__Opportunity__c;
            lstOpportunityToUpdate.add(opp);
        }
        system.debug('## lstPaymentToUpdate.size() ===>'+lstPaymentToUpdate.size());
        system.debug('## lstPaymentToUpdate ===>'+lstPaymentToUpdate);
        if(lstPaymentToUpdate.size()>0) {
            update lstPaymentToUpdate;
            system.debug('## lstPaymentToUpdate After===>'+lstPaymentToUpdate);
        }
        
        system.debug('## lstOpportunityToUpdate.size() ===>'+lstOpportunityToUpdate.size());
        system.debug('## lstOpportunityToUpdate ===>'+lstOpportunityToUpdate);
        if(lstOpportunityToUpdate.size()>0) {
            update lstOpportunityToUpdate;
            system.debug('## lstOpportunityToUpdate After===>'+lstOpportunityToUpdate);
        }
    }                
}


/**
* @User story: Validation Improvements JIRA ticket PFM-1082 Scenario 3,4
* @Method name: validateAllocation 
* @Description: prevent saving of GAU Allocation start with 49999
* @Param: new list and old list
* @Return: none
* @Date: 14 Feb 2022
**/
public static void validateAllocation(List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c> lstDataImport,List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c>  oldList){                 
    Map<Id,npsp__DataImportBatch__c> oldMap= new Map<Id,npsp__DataImportBatch__c>(oldList);
    Set<ID> batchIdSet = new Set<ID>();
    for(npsp__DataImportBatch__c obj : lstDataImport){
        npsp__DataImportBatch__c olddata=oldMap.get(obj.Id);
        if(olddata.NGOC_Batch_Status__c=='Open' && 
           (obj.NGOC_Batch_Status__c=='Ready to Commit' || 
            obj.NGOC_Batch_Status__c=='Ready to Post' || 
            obj.NGOC_Batch_Status__c=='Closed') ){
                batchIdSet.add(obj.id);
            }                
    }

    Set<Id> gauStartWith49999Set = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> allocationsOutOfBalanceSet = new Set<Id>();
    if(batchIdSet.size()>0){            
            for(npsp__Allocation__c allo:getAllocationByBatchId(batchIdSet)){                   
                if(allo.npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__r.Name.startsWith('49999')){//11502
                    if(string.isNotBlank(allo.Batch__c)){
                        gauStartWith49999Set.add(allo.Batch__c);
                    }
                    else if(string.isNotBlank(allo.npsp__Payment__r.Batch__c)){
                        gauStartWith49999Set.add(allo.npsp__Payment__r.Batch__c);
                    }
                    
                }
                if(allo.Allocations_out_of_balance__c){
                    if(string.isNotBlank(allo.Batch__c)){
                        allocationsOutOfBalanceSet.add(allo.Batch__c);
                    }
                    else if(string.isNotBlank(allo.npsp__Payment__r.Batch__c)){
                        allocationsOutOfBalanceSet.add(allo.npsp__Payment__r.Batch__c);
                    }                       
                }
            }
    }
    for(npsp__DataImportBatch__c obj : lstDataImport){
        if(gauStartWith49999Set.contains(obj.Id)){
            obj.addError('This Batch contains Allocation with 49999 code');
        }
        if(allocationsOutOfBalanceSet.contains(obj.Id)){
            obj.addError('Allocations are out of Balance');
        }
    }
    
}

/**
* @User story: PFM-1082
* @Method name: getAllocationByBatchId 
* @Description: SOQL on Allocation and return list
* @Param: Set of ids of Batches
* @Return: List of Allocation
* @Date: 14 Feb 2022
**/
public static List<npsp__Allocation__c> getAllocationByBatchId(Set<Id> batchIdSet){ 
   return [select npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__r.Name,Batch__c,Allocations_out_of_balance__c,npsp__Payment__r.Batch__c 
                                                      from npsp__Allocation__c where 
                                                      (Batch__c IN:batchIdSet OR npsp__Payment__r.Batch__c IN:batchIdSet)];
}  

/**
* @User story: PFM-271
* @Method name: validateBatch 
* @Description: try to validate batch againset "Allocation out of balance", "Invalid Allocation", and Batch and Payment date mismatched
* @Param: List of Batches and a boolen variables
* @Return: None
* @Date: 23 Mar 2022
**/
public static void validateBatch(List<npsp__DataImportBatch__c> lstBatches,Boolean isNeedUpdate) {
    List<npe01__OppPayment__c> lstPayments = getPaymentMethods(new Set<Id>(new Map<id,npsp__DataImportBatch__c>(lstBatches).keyset()));
    Map<Id,Boolean> mapBatchHaveMismatchDate = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
    Map<Id,Boolean> mapOutOfBalanceBatch = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
    Map<Id,Boolean> mapInvalidAllocation = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
    
    for(npe01__OppPayment__c pay : lstPayments) {
        if(pay.npe01__Payment_Date__c != pay.Batch__r.Batch_Entry_Date__c)  {
            mapBatchHaveMismatchDate.put(pay.Batch__c,True);
        } 
        if(pay.Allocations_Out_of_Balance__c)  {
            mapOutOfBalanceBatch.put(pay.Batch__c,True);
        }
        if(pay.Invalid_GAU_Allocation__c)  {
            mapInvalidAllocation.put(pay.Batch__c,True);
        }                                  
    }

    for(npsp__DataImportBatch__c batch : lstBatches) {
        if(mapBatchHaveMismatchDate.containsKey(batch.Id)) {
            batch.Payment_Date_Not_Matched__c = true;
        } else {
            batch.Payment_Date_Not_Matched__c = false; 
        }
        
        if(mapOutOfBalanceBatch.containsKey(batch.Id)) {
            batch.Allocations_Out_of_Balance__c = true;
        } else {
            batch.Allocations_Out_of_Balance__c = false; 
        }
        
        if(mapInvalidAllocation.containsKey(batch.Id)) {
            batch.Invalid_GAU_Allocation__c = true;
        } else {
            batch.Invalid_GAU_Allocation__c = false; 
        } 
        
    }
    if(isNeedUpdate) {
        database.update(lstBatches, false);
    }    
}

/**
* @User story: PFM-271
* @Method name: getPaymentMethods 
* @Description: SOQL on Related Payment objects of batch
* @Param: Set of Batch Ids
* @Return: List of payments
* @Date: 23 Mar 2022
**/
private static List<npe01__OppPayment__c> getPaymentMethods(Set<Id> setBatchIds) {
    Map<Id,Boolean> mapBatchHaveMismatchDate=new Map<Id,Boolean>();
    return [select id
                    ,Batch__c 
                    ,Batch__r.Batch_Entry_Date__c
                    ,npe01__Payment_Date__c
                    ,Allocations_Out_of_Balance__c
                    ,Invalid_GAU_Allocation__c
                    from npe01__OppPayment__c 
                    where Batch__c =: setBatchIds   
                    and npe01__Payment_Amount__c > 0];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Salesforce txn limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#in_topic_per_transaction_section) apply to each transaction as a whole. All cpu time consumed in that txn is counted towards the limit including apex code, workflow execution, partial dml/soql execution time etc.,

If you are running into this, first thing to do is generate a debug log and examine the log. It should give you sufficient details to identify code block which is taking significant time.